# How to remove unnecessary strings in Query String in PHP?

Tags: php, query-string

I am a total noob in programming so pls be patient with me. My question might look stupid to you.

I have here a query string:

> http://localhost/exercises/php_js/exer_test/?year_list=1994&event_list=Singing+Contest&btn_show=Show

I think the `&btn_show=Show` has something to do with the value of the submit element. Is there a way that I can remove or hide that in the Query string or URL?

**`index.php`**

```
<?php include('functions.php'); ?>

<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="myscripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <form name="myform" >
   Select Year: <?php echo hspacer(1); ?>
   <select id="year_list" name="year_list" >
   <?php  
    for($year = (date('Y') - 100); $year <= (date('Y') + 100); $year++ ) {
     if ($year == date('Y'))  echo "<option value='$year' name='$year' selected='' >" . $year . "</option>";
     else echo "<option value='$year' name='$year' >" . $year . "</option>";
    }
   ?>
   </select>
   <?php echo hspacer(5); ?>
   Select Event:  <?php echo hspacer(1); ?>
   <select id="event_list" name="event_list" >
   <?php  
    $events = array("Karate Tournament", "Beauty Pageant", "Film Festival", "Singing Contest", "Wedding");

    foreach($events as $event) echo "<option value='$event' name='$event' >" . $event . " </option>";
   ?>
   </select>
   <?php echo vspacer(2); echo hspacer(22); ?>
   <input type="submit" id="bnt_show" name="btn_show" value="Show" onclick="show(); "/> 
  </form>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**`functions.php`**

```
<?php
 function hspacer($num_of_spaces) {
  $spaces = "";
  if ($num_of_spaces > 0)  for($i=0; $i<$num_of_spaces; $i++ )  $spaces .= "&nbsp;";

  return $spaces;
 }

 function vspacer($num_of_linefeeds) {
  $linefeeds = "";
  if ($num_of_linefeeds > 0)  for($i=0; $i<$num_of_linefeeds; $i++ )  $linefeeds .= "<br />";

  return $linefeeds;
 }
?>
```

**`myscripts.js`**

```
function show() {
 var year = document.getElementById('year_list').value;
 var event = document.getElementById('event_list').value;
 var result = "Year: " + year + "\nEvent: " + event;

 alert(result);
}
```

Comment: I think you are looking for `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. You can find the documentation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can remove the name (e.g. `name="btn_show"`) to remove the query string in the URL.

```
<input type="submit" id="bnt_show" value="Show" onclick="show(); "/>
```

Answer (score 4):

Just remove the `name` from your submit button element.

Answer (score 1):

Just complete your form tag by adding the method parameter. Eg. `method="post"`. If you do so, the variables within the form will be passed to the web server by HTTP POST. Afterwards, you can find the variables within PHP in the `$_POST` array.

Check out the following url for a complete `FORM` Tag description.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are not using the value, remove the value from the input element of the submit button, or use the button-tag.

If you are using the value it would be correct to put it in the url as well.